# which index gets automatically created when we create primary key and unique key in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, indexing, oracle11g, oracle10g

I would like to know which index gets automatically created when we create primary key and unique key on Oracle table. 
Assume that there is no index present on table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle will create a unique index in both cases. A primary key can not contain null values. A unique key can.

If you want to try and see what happens, information about indexes is available in the user_indexes view.